# Error in Router.php after composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

After firing composer update on Laravel Framework 5.5.44, i see this error and app goes down.

[image]

I have compared the vendor/laravel folder before and after composer update and it is same. Nothing is added or removed.

Please help me with the possible cause of this error.

Comment: Can you post your routes here ?

Comment: The cause of the error is likely cached routes. You might have had you routes cached before running `composer update`. That command then "popped" the cache, causing new errors you've introduced to be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in your web.php file. Where you define a group which is not proper.
Your group route should look like this,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
      // your  route is here
});
```

Update this line code 
Form,

```
// Guest
Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'guest', 'fw-block-bl'], function () {
});
```

To,

```
// Guest
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['guest', 'fw-block-bl']], function () {
});
```

Comment: But it was working before the update: please access the link for web.php

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wno8gam5sirwcj3/Document.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Going from the document posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913070/error-in-router-php-after-composer-update#comment94670481_53913332):

Your issue seems to be in the `Route::group()` call right under `// User`:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'guest', 'fw-block-bl'], function () {
    // ...
});
```

The `fw-block-bl` middleware isn't properly being applied, and the framework doesn't know what to do with that piece. Either wrap the middleware in an array (like below), or use a chained method (`Route::group(function () { /*  */ })->middleware('guest', 'fw-block-bl');`)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest', 'fw-block-bl'], function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I made some changes and unable to fix the issue. Actually I am new to Laravel framework. I really appreciate if you please update the file and sent it to me.